# calculate email hash for email using sha256

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, hotmail, sha256

I am trying to retrieve contacts from hotmail in asp.net mvc. The response of hotmail api contains email as email hash and i know we cannot decrypt that email address hash. and There i saw one more field name field that contains actual contact email address.how could i calculate hash for that email address using sHA56 hasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about that? It assumes the strings to hash are encoded in UTF-8, the article you linked doesnt mention the Encoding that should be used.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace TestSHAHash
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string email = "Someone@Example.org";
            string clientId = "0000000603DB0F";

            string toHash = (email.Trim() + clientId.Trim()).ToLowerInvariant();
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toHash);
            byte[] result;
            SHA256 shaM = new SHA256Managed();
            result = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
            string lowerHexaDecimal = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-","").ToLowerInvariant();
            Console.WriteLine(lowerHexaDecimal);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But the result of calculating hash for email address by following the article [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826530.aspx#generating) was not matched with Email hash in hotmail api response.

Comment: edited based on the information available in the article you linked

Comment: You are following the 6 steps in that article and using the above SHA256Managed code to do step #5 correct?  Obviously if you don't follow all of the preceding steps or the subsequent step then it won't have the same result.